# How are the kernel page tables shared among all processes?

Tags: kernel, memory, virtual-memory

I’m trying to better understand on, say, x86, how the kernel is mapped into every process address space such that changing what a kernel address maps to is able to change in all processes and all cores. For a concrete example, say kernel address 0xC0000004 gets mapped to page frame 1000 during a syscall occurring in process A.

My question is: how do those mappings get updated for processes B and C running possibly concurrently on multiple cores and also for processes that are currently not running?

I'm assuming there must be some way to have all the processes "point" at / reference only one central set of kernel page tables, so that updates to that one, central location means a change in all processes. But then how would multi core systems handle this if each core has its own MMU? A walkthrough with an example might be really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I don't have time to write a proper answer right now, so just a few pointers that can get you started until someone answers: The page tables are system-wide and located in RAM, which is shared by all cores/MMUs. Google "TLB shootdown" to see how a single core tells other MMUs to discard their cached TLB entries and re-read the shared page tables. Also, nowadays in the post-Meltdown world, many systems are using PTI (page table isolation), which means that the kernel has its own set of page tables separate from userspace processes.

Comment: Thank you! That helps to answer one of the components of my question. For the other, in the pre-KPTI world, if each process had an entire set of page tables, how was the kernel virtual address space mapped into every process without just duplicating everything and making it such that a change in one central location meant a change for all the kernel mappings for every process? I was thinking all processes page directories pointed to the exact same memory location of the shared kernel page tables somehow...

Answer (score 1):

Page table hierarchy is the answer. The Linux page table is broken up into several levels, which means translating a single address can trigger several lookups as we descend into the page tables looking for a valid `pte`. This is usually thought of as a space optimization (only store page tables for valid memory locations instead of for the entire process address space). But for the kernel, it's also a performance optimization because it means existing kernel page table mappings can be reused between processes.

The reason kernel mapping updates aren't as big of a deal as you initially thought is because, typically, your example of a kernel address space changing would happen at a level lower than the page global directory (PGD), the highest page table level for each process. As implied by the explanation of kernel page table isolation ([KPTI](https://lwn.net/Articles/741878/)), if you can remove the kernel mapping from a process' page global directory, the process should not be able to access any kernel code. This implies that all process PGDs point to the same lower level kernel page tables. Any kernel memory update on these lower page tables will be visible to all processes with just the one update in memory, assuming a single core. Of course, this update will need to be propagated to all CPUs, but that's just a normal cache coherency update. Way less intense than manually updating a mapping for every single process that runs in a computer.